# SQL Merge Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, merge

Is there any difference between:

```
merge INTO cdm.ma_participant part 
  USING MA_USER.D_CONT_METR_01_00_25_52 metr 
  ON (part.participant_id=metr.participant_id AND metr.main_prior > 1)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE
  SET part.DEACTIVATED_FLG      = 'Y',
    part.DEACTIVATION_REASON_CD = 8,
    part.DEACTIVATION_DTTM      = sysdate,
    part.DEACTIVATION_ACTION_ID = 68215;
```

and:

```
merge INTO cdm.ma_participant part 
  USING (SELECT * FROM MA_USER.D_CONT_METR_01_00_25_52 WHERE main_prior > 1) metr 
  ON (part.participant_id=metr.participant_id)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE
  SET part.DEACTIVATED_FLG      = 'Y',
    part.DEACTIVATION_REASON_CD = 8,
    part.DEACTIVATION_DTTM      = sysdate,
    part.DEACTIVATION_ACTION_ID = 68215;
```

I want to find out the best optimised variant. The first one takes about 30 minutes.

Comment: Run them both -> run execution plan -> compare.

Comment: As sagi said please explain plans for both queries and compare. If you have problem with understanding explained plans please add both to your question.

Comment: And, you should expect, when you look at the plans, that the optimizer transformed the first version into the second. They should take the same time, because the optimizer would do what you would do: it would consider both options anyway, and pick the more efficient one.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I dont have opportunity to run execution plan, but I want to find the best variant to make an update my table.